# Plaster board abandoned in my house

Tags: asbestos

My tenants have left behind some pink/white plaster boards in my rental property.

I've just noticed there might be asbestos in it as there are white strands in the plaster.

I've double bagged the boards now.

Also, the tenants were plasterers but seemingly not the best as the company they worked for went bust. So maybe they might have not been very knowledgeable on hazardous materials.

I've got a photo and one zoomed in on the strands (not the best quality ) [image]

[image]

Comment: Modern gypsum wallboard panels often have fiberglass in them for strength and fire resistance. Can you identify a manufacturer?

Comment: I'm not at the house at the moment but tomorrow I'll try to see. Where would I find it?

Comment: Stamped on the back side, usually.

Comment: That stuff would have to be from the 70s or earlier to have asbestos in it. Also, as a tip for future reference, while the strands are visible a solid black background would have made them stand out in the picture much better.

Comment: Would it say the manufacturing date on the board?. Absolutely with the background, I was too scared to handle it too much so just took a photo as fast as I could

Comment: I have never known a dry waller to save Bits and pieces (or scabs from old work) what I think you are looking at is the heavy paper that binds 2 sheets together for shipping it makes them stronger and the finish surfaces are protected because they are together, the chance of any drywall found today containing asbestos is smaller than getting struck by lightning twice. But yes prior to the ban 84 asbestos was still found in some products.

Comment: I'd wager large sums of money it's not asbestos; the pink board is fire retardant plasterboard. The fibres are fibreglass reinforcement. Either way, it would perhaps help you sleep easier if you adjust your perspective on asbestos; a) it's asbestos, not anthrax, b) asbestos fibers occur widespread in the environment and you breathe tens of thousands of them over your life, c) asbestos that is captive in another material is safe to handle and d) https://www.shponline.co.uk/occupational-health/one-fibre-really-kill-asbestos-real-perceived-risk-part-1/ - you're a victim of media FUD, I think...

Comment: But... disposing of drywall board must be done as a hazardous substance no matter what, so leave it double bagged and find out where you can take it in your area.

Comment: I'm on my way to look for a manufacturing date on the board, so I'll try to update soon. Thanks all for reassuring me, hopefully it's not a matter to be worried about.